# Why are some of my files' names are not being displayed in OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

Some of my files' names are not being displayed in OS X as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image].

I have also uploaded a video to demonstrate this issue:

> [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gl7AN7UPkKg)

Any ideas what is wrong and how I can fix it?

EDIT : Uploaded snap-shot from terminal after `ls -B`

[image]

Comment: What does `ls -B` say about it?

Comment: @lgnacio - I have edited the question & uploaded a snap for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be displaying MP3 tags and not filenames?

Comment: If it is the case then How does it displays the name of audio file, when I click on it. Should I send you the audio file ? for your testing purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes does rely on MP3 tags(which iTunes is willing to rename the file to, but that's another matter). However, if you show it in list view, then click right next to the icon, where the name would be, then you can edit the MP3 tag to have something there. Alternatively, you can hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> and edit it there, although you might have to switch to a different section that I don't know off the top of my head.